# Data Frame from Matrix having indices

Tags: r

I have a matrix which has the indices of columns of a data frame. I want to construct a another data frame using the value corresponding to the index, in the same order as in the matrix.

The matrix was created as a result of `m1 <- sapply(df[,5:58],function(x){order(-x)})` where df is the original dataframe with 258 rows and 59 columns. The matrix(258x54) is a result of sorting each of the 54 columns of the data frame independently as I want to create a dataframe have the top 10 values for each column.

How do I get the result dataframe from the matrix indices(m1) which will have the values corresponding to the original dataframe (df) but in the order specified by the matrix position. A for loop could be a solution to build the data frame, but is there an apply or other function to do this?

I found a solution using mapply:

```
matrix(mapply(function(x,y){df[x,y]},
               as.list(t(m1)),rep((5:58),258)),
       nrow=258,ncol=54,byrow=T)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted. May be `sapply(df[,5:58],function(x) x[order(-x)])`

Comment: Found a solution as per my update to the post.

Comment: Glad you updated. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't answer by editing the question. Post the solution as an answer instead. However, I suspect there is a better (read more efficient) way to do this. Sadly, I don't fully understand the question and thus can't answer it.

Comment: Seems like this also works `matrix(df[cbind(c(t(m1)),rep(5:58,258))], nrow=258, ncol=54, byrow=T)`, not tested

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, if the data is (though I didn't fully understand the logic):

```
 set.seed(14)
 dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:80, 258*59,replace=TRUE), ncol=59))
 m1 <- sapply(dat[,5:58], function(x) order(-x))
 res1 <-  matrix(dat[cbind(c(t(m1)),rep(5:58,258))],nrow=258, ncol=54, byrow=TRUE)
```

Your solution

```
 res2 <- matrix(mapply(function(x,y){dat[x,y]},
           as.list(t(m1)),rep((5:58),258)),
   nrow=258,ncol=54,byrow=T)

   identical(res1,res2)
  #[1] TRUE
```